# How to keep selection when paging thru a view?

Tags: xpages

I have a simple view ( first column shows checkbox ) with a pager on top. I would like to make a selection of documents that then will be exported to Excel ( using apache POI ).

I can select 2 documents on page 1, but when I switch to another page to select more documents, all my selection on page 1 is gone.

How can I keep selection when paging thru the view??

Answer (score 2):

Retrieving a list of selected ids can be done with

```
viewPanel.getSelectedIds()
```

but I assume, because of your question, this is for the current page only. A solution would be to add a custom checkbox column with a serverside onclick event which will add the 
current selected notedid into a scoped var (containing a vector). On load of the row you will check if this var is found and if so check the checkbox. When you switch between pages you can select more documents.

When you are done selecting, you can use the generated vector to generate the excel document. After generation is done clean the scoped var again and you are done.

Easy as pie ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [pagerSaveState](http://www.openntf.org/xspext/xpages%20extension%20library%20documentation.nsf/xpages-doc/xe_pagerSaveState.html) in the Extension Library?

Not sure how much of the state information it stores.

Comment: No, does not work. Have used the example in the extLib Sample Db ( Domino_ViewState) and modified the first column to display checkboxes.
The expand/collapse is stored, but the checked boxes aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Ulrich,

It would be a bit brute force; but I may have a suggestion. I don't have time to implement it, but I'll try to explain how it works.

We have two problems here. we have to save selected items on one page and restore them if you return to the same page again.

Usual checkbox in view columns doesn't work, because we are not allowed to inject in its events. So you have to create your own checkbox inside the column, with a value of note id.

Selected IDs might be stored inside the viewScope. In the checkbox, you should check or uncheck the checkbox according to the list stored in viewScope.

You also create an RPC control to communicate with the viewscope object in the background. It has to have a single method: rpc.myMethod(noteId, checked). It will get the noteId, add to/delete from the viewScope.

```
<xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn3" displayAs="hidden">
<xp:this.facets>
    <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header" id="viewColumnHeader3"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:this.facets>
<input class="xspCheckBoxViewColumn" type="checkbox" value="#{javascript:viewEntry.getNoteID()}" style="margin: 0px 2px; height: 12px;" onChange="rpc.myMethod(this.value, this.checked)"/></xp:viewColumn>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yiyim, teşekkür ederim. I will give it a try.