# Keeping selections on viewpanel check boxes?

Tags: xpages

I searched and found some solutions for this but none of them seemed very attractive.

When a view is paged, the previous selections in the column check boxes are lost.

Has anyone come up with an easy way to keep the previous selections.

This is a really annoying feature of viewpanels, any  chance it will be fixed in the futur?

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of this (which doesn't have an accepted answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513892/how-to-keep-selection-when-paging-thru-a-view

Comment: I am not sure if the IBM will give you an answer to your question on stackoverflow.com....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1062 for an xSnippet that will do what you re asking for

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  Will see you in January. :)

Answer (score -2):

var viewPanel = getComponent("viewPanel2");

viewPanel.getSelectedIds().toString();

It wil return the NotesID of the selected Documents.

Comment: Sorry, have to down vote: The *getSelectedIds()* works only for current page.